# Setting filterId in ApexStandardSetController

Tags: standardsetcontroller

I am trying to filter the records based on the selected list view in batch apex. But it fetches all the records and does not apply the filter even though i have used setFilterId

```
    String query ='Select Id FROM '+objectName;
    ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc = 
         new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(query));          
    ssc.setFilterId(filterId);
    ssc.setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE);
    Map<Id,Sobject> sobjMap = new Map<Id,Sobject>();

    /**
    * Get all the records id and add it to set
    */
    while(true){
        sobjMap.putAll(ssc.getRecords());
        if(ssc.getHasNext()){
            ssc.next();
        }
        else{
                break;
        }
    }
    system.debug(sobjMap.size());
    return sobjMap.keySet();    `
```

Comment: Try setting the page size before the filter id?

Comment: Does it work from a none batch apex environment?

Comment: Checking will let you know in sometime

Comment: Setting the page size before filter id worked.. Thanks

Comment: Great, I've posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the filter id after the page size, like so ...

```
String query ='Select Id FROM '+objectName;
ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc = 
     new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(query));          
ssc.setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE);
ssc.setFilterId(filterId);
```

I imagine internally changing the page size causes the cursor maintained by the controller to reset and reset the filtering.

Comment: I was bedeviled by this as well, this works too once you have the ssc object instantiated: `this.ssc.setPageNumber(1);    this.ssc.setFilterId(filterId);`